# Why do I get "incompatible error" while opening .sh files using vi in cygwin?

Tags: bash, error

I am very much annoyed by this error:

```
$ vi abc.sh
Error detected while processing /home/DELL/.virc:
line    1:
E518: Unknown option: incompatible
Press ENTER or type command to continue
/bin/bash: line 2: \: command not found
```

I don't know, how it is affecting my programs and how this error occurred in my laptop?

I tried reinstalling the package, too.

Comment: I’ve added an answer below based on a guess but providing the contents of your virc would be extremely helpful

Comment: Did you read the error message? What is on line 1 of your .virc?

Comment: It is "set incompatible" on the first line of .virc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option name is `nocompatible`. Replace  `incompatible` with `nocompatible` to solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah! This worked for me